# Combining CSS attribute selectors input[type = "text"] and input[type="email"]

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Is there a short syntax for combining the following:

```
$(`input[type="text"], input[type="email"]`).click(...);
```

I've tried:

```
input[type="text"][type="email"]

input[type="text|email"]

input[type="text"|"email"]
```

But those don't work.

Comment: @Quentin, how it's a duplicate?

Comment: The comma is the only syntax for combining multiple, independent selectors with a rule-set.

Comment: @TemaniAfif — You want a selector that matches multiple elements with different selectors (i.e. `input[type="text"]` and `input[type="email"]`). That's what the duplicate is about.

Comment: @Quentin yes, he basically know this and he's probably looking for anoher way to target both input with the same selector .. I agree there is no generic rules but probably there is some workaround with jQuery for example to reduce the selector (ex :`[type="text"],[type="email"]`, without `input`)